# Color selection

Tags: color

Welcome everybody.
I have to use several colors in my text (more than 10). I want to build a command that takes 2 mandatories (the word and the color number) and prints the given word with the desired color.  The following MWE gives more details:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\colorlet{col1}{red}
\colorlet{col2}{green}
\colorlet{col3}{blue}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cText}{mm}{\textcolor{#2}{#1}}

\begin{document}
  this is \cText{red}{col1}, this is \cText{green}{col2} and this is \cText{blue}{col3}.
  this is \cText{another red}{col1}, this is \cText{another green}{col2} and this is \cText{another red}{col1}.
  % The desired version is 
  %this is \cText{red}{1}, this is \cText{green}{2} and this is \cText{blue}{3}.
  %this is \cText{another red}{1}, this is \cText{another green}{2} and this is \cText{another red}{1}.{3}.
\end{document}
```

Any help, especially based on `expl3`, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Why don't you use `\textcolor{color}{text}`?

Comment: Nice suggestion. I updated my code.

Comment: I think if you change your command to `\NewDocumentCommand{\cText}{mm}{\textcolor{col#2}{#1}}` it'll do what you want.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the command you are trying to create? I don't see a reason for you to "recreate" it that way. You could write something like `\let\cText\textcolor` to use it rather than recreating a new macro that does exactly the same.

Comment: OK. I think I didn’t express myself well. I have many words that have to be with the same color. I updated the MWE so this may help. To make it easier this command is well defined for this purpose.

Comment: but what you like to obtain can be done with `\textcolor{<desired color>}{colored word(s)}`. for this you not need any complication with new macro. you only need to define meaningful short names for your colors and that is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a simpler interface for defining the colors. The “left-hand side” can be any string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_aloui_colors_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\setdocumentcolors}{m}
 {
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_aloui_colors_prop { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\cText}{mm}
 {
  \textcolor{ \prop_item:Nn \g_aloui_colors_prop { #2 } } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setdocumentcolors{
  1=red,
  2=green,
  3=blue,
  x=pink,
}

\begin{document}

\cText{red}{1} \cText{green}{2} \cText{blue}{3} \cText{pink}{x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are awsome. This is exactly what I need.